# Using SDL with XCode 4.4

Tags: xcode, sdl

I am trying to use XCode 4.4 to run SDL but am running into problems. I followed the directions exactly from this site http://www.lazyfoo.net/SDL_tutorials/lesson01/mac/xcode/index.php but it did not compile and gave me the following error.

> Ld
>   /Users/Jeffrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_test1-gymiyuicyswxljbpwkggciejevaj/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_test1
>   normal x86_64
>       cd /Users/Jeffrey/Documents/Documents/Engineering/SDL_test1
>       setenv MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET 10.8
>       /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang++
>   -arch x86_64 -isysroot /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.8.sdk
>   -L/Users/Jeffrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_test1-gymiyuicyswxljbpwkggciejevaj/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/Users/Jeffrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_test1-gymiyuicyswxljbpwkggciejevaj/Build/Products/Debug
>   -F/Library/Frameworks -filelist /Users/Jeffrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_test1-gymiyuicyswxljbpwkggciejevaj/Build/Intermediates/SDL_test1.build/Debug/SDL_test1.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/SDL_test1.LinkFileList
>   -mmacosx-version-min=10.8 -framework SDL -framework Cocoa -o /Users/Jeffrey/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/SDL_test1-gymiyuicyswxljbpwkggciejevaj/Build/Products/Debug/SDL_test1
>
> Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:   "_main", referenced from:
>        -u command line option
>        (maybe you meant: _SDL_main) ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64 clang: error: linker command failed with exit code
>   1 (use -v to see invocation)

the only discrepancy is in step 9 (Go into the SDLmain.m template file you added and change #include "SDL.h" to #include "SDL/SDL.h") I didn't actually find the include statement but instead an import statement. I tried both ways, however.
Any help would be appreciated. 
I am using a Macbook Pro with the Mountain Lion operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if you are still having trouble with this but if you are I have made a couple of tutorials for OSX getting SDL set up.

Xcode - [Setup SDL on OSX in Xcode](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-xcode-osx/)

Eclipse - [Setup SDL on OSX in Eclipse](http://zamma.co.uk/setup-sdl2-in-eclipse-osx/)

The Xcode version has a link to my Xcode SDL2 template which makes starting up very easy.